# Entity Framework doesn't use users default schema

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

On my SQL Server I have a user called "preview" which has the default schema "preview". Even though I have this user in my connection string, the Entity Framework always uses the dbo schema. Is this normal behaviour or is something wrong with my SQL server configuration?

I know I could define a different schema with the `TableAttribute` or the `ModelBuilder` but I   really try to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes for EF version <=5. There will be new features in EF6 to achieve what you need.
See here for explanation, under DbModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=specs

Comment: You refer to **DbModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema**. But that is still far from automatically taking the default schema of a login user. The answer should be that the mapping rules. As far as I know EF is not even aware of a user's default schema.

Comment: @GertArnold I agree, but maybe it would be possible to configure default schema in runtima based on active user.. Don't know enough about OPs requirements, but if only one users is using the DbContext, he should be able to set the default schema for the active user. SemiAutomatic, but still avoids hard coding schema into every table.

Comment: My only requirement is to change the schema on runtime. So `Db.ModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema` might be a good solution. I will now take a look at the EF 6 Alpha release. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've just upgraded to EF 6-alpha3 and tried the new `ModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema` and it's working great. That's a good solution for me. Thanks again.

Comment: --> `DbModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema` working perfectly for me, thank you